# WKWebview runs fine in iOS 10, freezes in iOS 9

Tags: ionic-framework, wkwebview

I installed the WKWebview plugin from driftyco Github page and my app runs normally in ios 10. However, when I installed the app on iOS 9, the app freezes at the splash screen.

I read about the ATS and in my info.plist, I have this value

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Here is my access-origin and allow-navigation tag

```
<access origin="*" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
```

What else do I need to do to make WKWebview work? I have WKWebview v1.1.1 and Cordova iOS 4.1.1.

I also noticed an error "DOM Exception 18: An attempt was made to break through the security policy of the user agent."

Another interesting error is

```
[Error] module cordova-plugin-nativestorage.NativeStorageError already defined
define (cordova.js:79)
Global Code (NativeStorageError.js:1)
[Error] Failed to load resource: unsupported URL (ready, line 0)
```

Please help!